# VS 2015 Default Web Application Identity Database Location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-identity

I created a web application in VS 2015. It has basic authentication build in and is functional.

Where is the data for account authentication stored?

There are no files in the App_Data folder where the documentation indicates it should be located.

I'm looking to move the data to a SQL Server to be mixed in with other outside data. But I have to find the existing files first.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use any of these approaches, to access database files.

1. Click `Show all files` button from the toolbar on top of solution explorer pane.
2. Right click `App_Data` folder from Solution Explorer and select `Open Folder in File Explorer` from menu.

Comment: Show all files is on and there is definitely not a file in that directory. Neither VS in the App_Data folder of Solution Explorer nor C:\Work Directory\RFI Website\RFI Website\App_Data show any files in them.

Comment: Did you already enabled migrations and executed `update-database` command? Also check your connectionstring for this parameter `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\your-aspwebapp.mdf`.